# How do you get this overlay effect on Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, overlay

I'm talking about this logo
[image: Logo]
I'm trying to make something with the same effect. I've tried a few things but can't really find the right mixture of what is used, the overlay just looks great on the one in the picture and it darkens the layer below it but mine just does that a little by using the multiply layer type. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Draw a shape, reduce the fill to like 10%, duplicate and rotate. Here I did it with 12% fill. No blend modes needed:

[image]

Comment: What did you draw your shape with? I drew mine with pen tool and filled it afterwards but it looks messy around the edges...

Comment: @DFSFOT the pen tool. After drawing I use the Direct Select (white) Arrow [keyboard: A] to adjust a little. Then go back to Pen Tool [keyboard: P] and hit Shape at the top. This is in CC. In older Photoshop its a square box with points around it.

Comment: We can do it using shapes and opacity, right? or it will create any diffrence?

Comment: @AbhishekSharma little late but yeah you can use shapes, I'd still put a fill on the layer though because it really has a different effect in comparison to opacity.